# didReceiveLocalNotification always fires on app launch

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to set up my app to open a specific page when opened from a local notification.  I have didReceiveLocalNotification set up to print the notification information.  This has been working for a few days but I just noticed today that when I launch my app from xcode, didReceiveLocalNotification is called and the information from the last scheduled notification (several hours before) is being printed.

Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    // If app is opened from a local notification while running in background, print notification info.
    if(application.applicationState == .Active){
        print(notification)
        print("app opened from notification")
    }
}
```

I've seen some threads where people are having didReceiveLocalNotification called twice for the same local notification, but this is different.  It's being called every single time I log in to the app, printing information about a notification that fired four hours ago.  How do I make sure that didReceiveLocalNotification is only called when the app is opened from a notification?

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can test it like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

        print("notification - tapped")

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
            print("App already open")

        } else {
            print("App opened from Notification")

            }
        }    
    }
```

You can close the app but do not terminate to test it.

Comment: When I use this code it prints "notification - tapped" every time I run my app even though there was no notification.

Comment: Yes because every time you set the notification, it tells that. You can remove that line if you wish. But it should tell you "App opened from Notification" if you opened it from notification.

Comment: I think I understand now.  I was using .Active when I should have been using .Inactive.  Thank you.